# Reading from string the Number in Python

Tags: python, string, function, numbers

I am currently having a problem when just reading the number from a string. I somehow does not receive the proper value. I need to distinguish between 1 and 2 numbered strings and need to account for it. My Output looks like the following:

> ```
> 9
> 1
> ```

but it should be:

> ```
> 9
> 10
> ```

```
def StringToNumber(Period):
    if Period[-1:] == "D":
        period_unit = int(Period[:1])
    elif Period[-1:] == 'M':
        period_unit = int(Period[:1])
    elif Period[-1:] == 'W':
        period_unit = int(Period[:1])
    elif Period[-1:] == 'Y':
        period_unit = int(Period[:1])
    elif Period == '':
        period_unit = int(0)
    else:
        raise Exception('Problems')
    return period_unit

years_string1 = '9Y'
years_string2 = '10Y'

years_number1 = StringToNumber(years_string1)
years_number2 = StringToNumber(years_string2)

print(years_number1)
print(years_number2)
```

Comment: do it all  : period_unit = int(Period[:-1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you try like this, if year_string is in same format

```
def StringToNumber(Period):
    period_unit = Period[:-1]
    return period_unit

years_string1 = '9Y'
years_string2 = '10Y'

years_number1 = StringToNumber(years_string1)
years_number2 = StringToNumber(years_string2)

print(years_number1)
print(years_number2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. To get the last element use **[-1]** instead of `[-1:]` . And to exclude the last element use **[:-1]** instead of `[:1]`

```
def StringToNumber(Period):
    if Period[-1] == "D":
        period_unit = int(Period[:-1])
    elif Period[-1] == 'M':
        period_unit = int(Period[:-1])
    elif Period[-1] == 'W':
        period_unit = int(Period[:-1])
    elif Period[-1] == 'Y':
        period_unit = int(Period[:-1])
    elif Period == '':
        period_unit = int(0)
    else:
        raise Exception('Problems')
    return period_unit

years_string1 = '9Y'
years_string2 = '10Y'

print(StringToNumber(years_string1))
print(StringToNumber(years_string2))
```

**Output:**

```
9
10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunatly someone was faster than you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `-1` instead of a `1`

Try this:

```
intervals = ['D', 'M', 'W', 'Y']
def StringToNumber(Period):

    if Period[-1:] in intervals:
        period_unit = int(Period[:-1])
    elif Period == '':
        period_unit = int(0)
    else:
        raise Exception('Problems')
    return period_unit

years_string1 = '9Y'
years_string2 = '10Y'

years_number1 = StringToNumber(years_string1)
years_number2 = StringToNumber(years_string2)

print(years_number1)
print(years_number2)
```

This makes your code a little nicer and decreases redundancy

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunatly someone was faster than you